# Saxon 8 - XQuery file - Java call

Tags: java, saxon

Now I have this error :

```
Error on line 10 of *module with no systemId*:
  FODC0005: Exception thrown by URIResolver: Invalid relative URI
  {D:\Users\***\workspace\**...}: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
  D:\Users\***\workspace\***/JDPR/config/Rules.xml
Error at xsl:copy-of on line 13 of *module with no systemId*:
  FODC0005: Exception thrown by URIResolver: Invalid relative URI
  {D:\Users\***\workspace\**...}: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
  D:\Users\***\workspace\***/JDPR/config/Rules.xml
; SystemID: *module with no systemId*; Line#: 13; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: Exception thrown by URIResolver
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.Document.makeDoc(Document.java:275)
```

The XQuery part related is :

```
(:declare namespace dpr="java:util.DPRConfigurationLoader";:)
declare namespace dpr="java:com.*****.common.util.DPRConfigurationLoader";
declare variable $rules as node()* := doc(dpr:getApplicationProperty('Common','RulesFileLocation'))//category;
```

If I run this xquery as shown here it gives me the error.
If I uncomment the first line and comment the second line the error does not appear.

In the Java program I modify the Xquery file and delete the string "com.*****.common." so that the line becomes the same as the commented line.

So I don't understand why one version is working fine and the other, which is the same at the moment of execution, does not.

If someone find where is the problem... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supplying a Windows filename (`D:\Users\***\workspace\**...`} to an interface that expects a URI.

I don't know what `dpr:getApplicationProperty()` does, but if there are two versions of it in different namespaces then they presumably do different things, so it's hardly surprising that one succeeds and the other fails.

The argument to the `doc()` function must be a URI, not a Windows filename.

Comment: Ok problem come from the "\".

To be a valid URI the string must contains only "/".

So I just changed the java method which give me the path so it replaces all "\" with "/" and it works now.


After investigations I guess the path was not exactly the same when the program worked... Still does not know where I made the mistake...

Anyway thanks for pointing the right way. :-)

Comment: The "D:" can also cause problems since it looks like an absolute URI with an unknown scheme "D".

Comment: In fact the program will run on Linux so the way the URI is created does not really matter as it should start with a folder name in all cases but I needed to make it to work to test it correctly and I am developing on Windows so... :-)